# ReferenceError: document is not defined when creating variable

Tags: javascript

I'm running my code in node.js I've seen that running code in node could play a part. But this was never a problem. It keeps saying my variable that points to my element 'document is not defined'. I don't know what I'm doing wrong, I'm linking it correctly but still confused I also tried putting my scripts on the bottom and top with defer.

```
let seconds = 00;
let tens = 00;
let appendTens = document.querySelector('#tens');
let appendSeconds = document.querySelector('#seconds');
let stop = document.querySelector('#button-stop');
let start = document.querySelector('#button-start');
let reset = document.querySelector('#button-reset');
let interval; //store timer values


// this function will run when start is clicked 

const startTimer = () =>{
    tens++

    if(tens < 9){
        appendTens.textContent = `0${tens}`
    }
    if(tens > 9){
        appendTens.textContent = tens;
    }
    if(tens > 99){
        seconds++
        appendSeconds.textContent = `0${seconds}`;
        tens = 0;
        appendTens.textContent = "0" + 0;
    }
    if(seconds > 9){
        appendSeconds.textContent = seconds;
    }
};

start.onclick = function(){
    interval = setinterval(startTimer)
}
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Stopwatch</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stopwatch.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <h1>Stopwatch</h1>
        <h2>Vanilla JavaScript Stopwatch</h2>
        <p><span id="seconds">00</span>:<span id="tens">00</span></p>
        <button id="button-start">Start</button>
        <button id="button-stop">Stop</button>
        <button id="button-reset">Reset</button>
        </div> 
        <script type="module" src="stopwatcj.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-self: center;
  background-color: rgb(248, 180, 55);
}

.wrapper {
  margin-top: 10%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}
.wrapper button {
  background-color: rgb(248, 180, 55);
  border: 1px solid white;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  color: #fff;
}
.wrapper button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 30%;
}
```

Comment: This looks like code meant to execute *on a page*, not in NodeJS.  There is no "document" in NodeJS.  In the HTML shown it looks like you're trying to include this code on that page, but in the question you say you're *"running my code in node.js"*, so it's not really clear what you're actually doing.

Comment: document resides in the global variable window, which is only available in the browser. Try running this in the browser.

Comment: Hello okay i ran it on a browser but its now saying 'from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, isolated-app, chrome-extension, chrome, https, chrome-untrusted.'  What does this mean?

Comment: and it works on codepen but not my laptop, weird.

Comment: setInterval is case is wrong `setinterval` != `setInterval`

Comment: @Angel94124: The code shown doesn't produce that error, because the code shown doesn't make any AJAX requests.  As for the AJAX request resulting in a CORS error, searching the exact error message in your favorite search engine will find lots of information about what CORS is and what that means.  At a high level, the browser blocks AJAX requests/responses to domains different than the current page unless those domains explicitly allow cross-origin requests.

Answer (score 1):

document which is a part of Html DOM is not a part of nodejs. Since you might be using nodejs to compile your js code that's why you are getting this error. Please try to run this simply in browser.